# The F3::clean() function doesn't work as expected in template

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

I want use the `F3::clean` function in a template but it doesn't work. The function doesn't remove HTML tags. When I use function in controller, everything is working fine.

```
{{ F3::clean(@servisItem.description, 'br') | raw }}
```

I want to display `servisItem.description` with `<br>` and any other
HTML code removed.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because variables passed to the template are HTML-escaped. Therefore there's no more any HTML tag to be stripped. See:

- inside controller: `<p>foo<br>bar</p>`
- inside template: `&lt;p&gt;foo&lt;br&gt;bar&lt;/p&gt;`

The best is to strip tags inside the controller, but if you absolutely need to do it inside the template, then you need to unstrip tags first:

```
{{ F3::clean(F3::decode(@servisItem.description), 'br') }}
```